# How to take percentages and make histogram in GGplot using results from tabyl

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How do I make a barplot using ggplot with my results from tabyl in R?

```
library(janitor)

dfpercentage <- tabyl(df1, severity, category, show_na = FALSE) %>% 
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits =1)
```

**Sample Data**

```r
structure(list(severity = c("Mild", "Moderate", "None", "Severe"
), cat1 = c("10.3%", "4.8%", "5.2%", "5.6%"), cat2 = c("8.7%", 
"1.6%", "10.9%", "16.7%"), cat3 = c("0.0%", "0.0%", "0.2%", "0.0%"
), cat4 = c("1.0%", "3.2%", "5.0%", "5.6%"), cat5 = c("0.3%", 
"0.0%", "0.3%", "0.0%"), cat6 = c("11.9%", "19.0%", "4.5%", "5.6%"
), cat7 = c("0.3%", "2.4%", "0.0%", "0.0%"), cat8 = c("1.0%", 
"0.8%", "1.5%", "0.0%"), cat9 = c("43.3%", "51.6%", "47.7%", 
"38.9%"), cat10 = c("23.4%", "16.7%", "24.7%", "27.8%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

```
  Severity       Cat1     Cat2    Cat3  Cat4  Cat5     Cat6    Cat7    Cat8   Cat9.  Cat10.
       Mild        10.3%   8.7%   0.0%  1.0%   0.3%    11.9%    0.3%    1.0%   43.3%  23.4%
   Moderate         4.8%   1.6%   0.0%  3.2%   0.0%    19.0%    2.4%    0.8%   51.6%  16.7%
       None         5.2%  10.9%   0.2%  5.0%   0.3%     4.5%    0.0%    1.5%   47.7%  24.7%
     Severe         5.6%  16.7%   0.0%  5.6%   0.0%     5.6%    0.0%    0.0%   38.9%  27.8%
```

I would like to have a result like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using the data you provided to create the following plot.

```r
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)

dfpercentage<- structure(list(severity = c("Mild", "Moderate", "None", "Severe"
), cat1 = c("10.3%", "4.8%", "5.2%", "5.6%"), cat2 = c("8.7%", 
"1.6%", "10.9%", "16.7%"), cat3 = c("0.0%", "0.0%", "0.2%", "0.0%"
), cat4 = c("1.0%", "3.2%", "5.0%", "5.6%"), cat5 = c("0.3%", 
"0.0%", "0.3%", "0.0%"), cat6 = c("11.9%", "19.0%", "4.5%", "5.6%"
), cat7 = c("0.3%", "2.4%", "0.0%", "0.0%"), cat8 = c("1.0%", 
"0.8%", "1.5%", "0.0%"), cat9 = c("43.3%", "51.6%", "47.7%", 
"38.9%"), cat10 = c("23.4%", "16.7%", "24.7%", "27.8%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

dfpercentage <- janitor::clean_names(dfpercentage)

dfpercentage %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -1,
               names_to = 'category',
               values_to = 'value') %>% 
  mutate(
    value = str_remove_all(value, '%'),
    value = as.double(value),
    value = value / 100,
    severity = factor(severity, levels = c('None', 'Mild', 'Moderate', 'Severe')),
    category = factor(category, levels = c('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat6', 'cat7', 'cat8', 'cat9', 'cat10'))
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = category, y = value, fill = category)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~severity, scales = 'free_x') +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these option based on your preference :

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


tabyl(df1, severity, category, show_na = FALSE) %>% 
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Severity) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, unique(name))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(name, value) + geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~Severity)
```

Or :

```
tabyl(df1, severity, category, show_na = FALSE) %>% 
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Severity) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, unique(name))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(name, value, fill = Severity) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```